# Selenium(Python): After clicking button, wait until all the new elements (which can have different attributes) are loaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How do I wait for all the new elements that appear on the screen to load after clicking a specific button? I know that I can use the `presence_of_elements_located` function to wait for specific elements, but how do I wait until all the new elements have loaded on the page? Note that these elements might not necessarily have one attribute value like class name or id.

Comment: (CORRECT ME SOMEONE, IF I AM WRONG) as far as I know thats kinda impossible to be done by python without using JavaScript ... problem with this, is that (Atleast I think its like that, cuz i tried to make i work many times) Selenium is using the html file that it optains on the openning of the website ... I might be wrong ... but If I am not, then u need to execute your command using somekina javascript (and if u want to scrape those data, that might be a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in reality you can't, but you can run a script to check for that.

However be wary that this will not work on javascript/AJAX elements.

`self.driver.execute_script("return document.readyState").equals("complete"))`